# php csv show question marks

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to export a CSV file, which is working all good when export. But there are some problems when I open my csv file, there are some text change to "??????". But in phpmyadmin there is all fine. The text is encoding by utf-8.

**Here is my code**

```
<?php
$day = $_POST['day'];

$starttime = "'".$day.' 00:00:00'."'";
$stoptime = "'".$day.' 23:59:59'."'";

$uname = "*********";
$pass = "*********";
$host = "*********"; 
$database = "*********"; 

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

echo mysql_error();
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

$output = "";
$table = "***********";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE applytime BETWEEN $starttime AND $stoptime");
$columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($sql);
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($rowcount >= 1)
{
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading =  mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output = '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

$filename =  "myFile.csv";

header("content-type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;
}

else
{
    echo("There is no record Today");
}

?>
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: How are you opening the file? Maybe the program you're using doesn't understand UTF-8 text, so it shows `?` in place of some characters

Comment: just click on the column or increase the width of column in opened CSV file.

Comment: @SumanSingh what will happen with your solution?

Comment: many time CSV show the '???' like date field but when we click on column it will show the current formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a call to the `mysql_set_charset` function.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Was that omission an oversight? Or was that purposefully omitted because its already been confirmed that the client characterset is set appropriately without that?

---

Why are we writing code that uses the *deprecated* `mysql_` functions, when both `mysqli` and `PDO` interfaces are available? And why are we writing code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection, by incorporating potentially unsafe values into SQL text?